# How do I make an NSCollectionView work with a Swift struct?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscollectionview

I have a model object that’s really a struct. I have an array of these and I would like to present this array in a collection view:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
    let item: SomeStructType = items[indexPath.item]
    return collectionView.newItemForRepresentedObject(item)
}
```

This doesn’t work, though, as the item is a struct and doesn’t conform to `AnyObject`. I would like to keep the model a struct, what options do I have? Boxing the items?

Comment: Are you using binding?